# Trying to add a text editor on my website

Tags: php, html

currently i am working on a site for question answer site.
it is like this stackoverflow.anyone help me to add text editor on my site

```
any plugin for text-edtor
```

the data entered in text editor stored into database.

i am using PHP

Comment: http://ckeditor.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this [link](http://blog.smartbear.com/programming/five-free-javascript-libraries-to-add-text-editing-to-your-web-application/). Its the 2nd search result on google when searched `"text editor api for websites"`

This is just what you want.

I prefer [QuillJS](http://quilljs.com/).

Here are some of its [examples](http://quilljs.com/examples/).

Answer (score 0):

i think ckeditor is best, Please check following link.

http://ckeditor.com/demo

Answer (score 0):

You can use code mirror, an open source text editor for web.

link : https://codemirror.net/